# Write a function that runs another function after adding a hook

Tags: hooks

I want to run some function `f` after adding a hook to a mode and after running `f` remove the hook that I added, returning the result of `f` if there is one.

Here is a non-working version that I hope makes the intent clear:

```
(defun run-function-with-hook (mode-hook hook-fn fn)
  (add-hook mode-hook hook-fn)
  (message (concat "mode hooks before running: " (prin1-to-string (symbol-value mode-to-slowdown))))
  (funcall fn)
  (remove-hook mode-hook hook-fn))

  (run-function-with-hook 'org-mode-hook (message "opening org file") (message "opened org file"))
```

Is this a better fit for a macro? If so, perhaps the right answer to this is an answer using a macro instead.

Comment: That's the usual way to do it, AFAIK: add-hook followed by remove-hook.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I had things mostly correct besides a variable I forgot to rename. The issue was that I needed to wrap the functions in `lambda` calls:

```
(defun run-function-with-hook (mode-hook hook-fn fn)
  (add-hook mode-hook hook-fn)
  (message (concat "mode hooks before running: " (prin1-to-string (symbol-value mode-hook))))
  (funcall fn)
  (remove-hook mode-hook hook-fn))

(run-function-with-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (message "opening org file")) (lambda () (message "opened org file")))
```

Comment: You might want to use `unwind-protect` in your `run-function-with-hook` to ensure that `remove-hook` happens.

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time with let-binding. For example, here I temporarily define the value of an org-mode hook. It automatically reverts outside the let  definition.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(let ((org-export-before-parsing-hook '(org-ref-cite-natmove)))
    (org-open-file (org-latex-export-to-pdf)))
#+END_SRC
```

or in this example, I temporarily remove the org-mode hook while opening a file:

```
(let* ((filename (pop org-db-queue))
       (org-mode-hook '())
       (enable-local-variables nil)
       (already-open (find-buffer-visiting filename))
       (buf (find-file-noselect filename)))
  (org-db-log "Updating %s" filename)
  (with-current-buffer buf
    (org-db-update-buffer force))
  (unless already-open (kill-buffer buf)))
```